# Can this script be used to create multiple SVG elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, charts

I have the following JavaScript that creates a graph using snap SVG.

However I need to create 4 SVG's in total and I was wondering if I could use only this script for it? And if so, how would I go about adjusting it? Or is it necessary with 4 seperate scripts to create the 4 SVG's?

In short; what's the best way going about this?

Thanks in advance.

The script:

```js
//#SVG

var price = [0,-50, -100, -130, -150, -200];

//CHART VALUES
var chartH = $('#svg').height();
var chartW = $('#svg').width();

// PARSE PRICES TO ALIGN WITH BOTTOM OF OUR SVG
var prices = [];
for (i = 0; i < price.length; i++) {
    prices[i] = price[i] + $('#svg').height();
}

function draw() {
    //DEFINE SNAP SVG AND DETERMINE STEP NO.
    var paper = Snap('#svg');
    var steps = prices.length;

    // EVENLY DISTRIBUTE OUR POINTS ALONG THE X AXIS

    function step(i, chartW) {
        return chartW / prices.length * i;
    }

    var points = [];
    var breakPointsX = [];
    var breakPointsY = [];
    var point = {};

    for (i = 1; i < prices.length; i++) {

        //CALCULATE CURRENT POINT

        var currStep = step(i, chartW);
        var y = prices[i];
        point.x = Math.floor(currStep);
        point.y = y;

        //CALCULATE PREVIOUS POINT

        var prev = i - 1;
        var prevStep = step(prev, chartW);
        var prevY = prices[prev];
        point.prevX = Math.floor(prevStep);
        point.prevY = prevY;
        if (point.prevX === 0 || point.prevY === 0){
          point.prevX = 15;
          point.prevY = chartH - 0
        }
        // SAVE PATH TO ARRAY
        points[i] = " M" + point.prevX + "," + point.prevY + " L" + point.x + "," + point.y;

        // SAVE BREAKPOINTS POSITION

        var r = 30;
        breakPointsX[i] = point.x;
        breakPointsY[i] = point.y;
    }

    // DRAW LINES

    for (i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        var myPath = paper.path(points[i]);
        var len = myPath.getTotalLength();
        myPath.attr({
            'stroke-dasharray': len,
                'stroke-dashoffset': len,
                'stroke': '#3f4db3',
                'stroke-linecap': 'round',
                'stroke-width': 6,
                'stroke-linejoin': 'round',
                'id': 'myLine' + i,
                'class': 'line'
        });
    }
    // DRAW BREAKPOINTS
    for (i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        var circle = paper.circle(breakPointsX[i], breakPointsY[i], 5);
        circle.attr({
            'fill': '#fff',
                'stroke': '#3f4db3',
                'stroke-width': 3,
                'id': 'myCirc' + i,
                'class':'breakpoint'
        });
    }
  // DRAW COORDINATE SYSTEM
    var xAxis = paper.path('M0,'+chartH+'L'+chartW+","+chartH);
    var yAxis = paper.path('M0,'+chartH+'L0,0');

  var xOff = xAxis.getTotalLength();
  var yOff = yAxis.getTotalLength();
  var start = (prices.length*250+"ms");

  yAxis.attr({
    'stroke':'black',
    'stroke-width':10,
    'stroke-dasharray':yOff,
    'stroke-dashoffset':yOff,
    'id':'yAxis'
  });
  xAxis.attr({
    'stroke':'black',
    'stroke-width':5,
    'stroke-dasharray':xOff,
    'stroke-dashoffset':xOff,
    'id':'xAxis'
  });
  console.log(start);
  $('#yAxis').css({
    '-webkit-transition-delay':start,
    '-webkit-transition':'all 200ms ease-in'
  });
   $('#xAxis').css({
    '-webkit-transition-delay':start,
    '-webkit-transition':'all 200ms ease-in'
  });
  $('#xAxis').animate({
    'stroke-dashoffset':'0'
  });
  $('#yAxis').animate({
    'stroke-dashoffset': '0'
  });
}
function animate(){
  for (i=0;i<prices.length;i++){
    var circ = $('#myCirc'+i);
    var line = $('#myLine'+i);
    circ.css({
      '-webkit-transition':'all 550ms cubic-bezier(.84,0,.2,1)',
      '-webkit-transition-delay':375+(i*125)+"ms"
      });
    line.css({
      '-webkit-transition':'all 250ms cubic-bezier(.84,0,.2,1)',
      '-webkit-transition-delay':i*125+"ms"
      });
    line.animate({
      'stroke-dashoffset':0
    });
    circ.css({
      'transform':'scale(1)'
    });
  }
}

var alreadyPlayed = false;

 $(window).load(function(){
 draw();
 animate();
 });
```

Comment: you'll end up with multiple identical id values, so no. Without some adjustment it's not reusable.

Comment: Can you, briefly, explain how you would go about using it to create 4 svgs? I have already tried just changing the #svg to #svg1 and have two scripts, one for each div. But this does not seem to work, so it would be awesome if you could point me in the right direction.